# Swift returning 0 on division

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do basic division and it always returns 0 as an answer.

```
let mathStuff = Double((stepCount / Level.expRequired())) * 100
print ("\(totalSteps) / \(Level.expRequired()) * 100 = \(mathStuff)")
```

My print returns

```
2117 / 2500 * 100 = 0.0
```

I've tried using NSDecimal instead of a Double and have also tried not using Double or NSDecimal and having it just do the math, which comes back as 0 instead of 0.0.

I'm really confused on what I'm doing wrong here, this seems like basic math and I'm not sure why I'm always given 0 as an answer.

Comment: your print uses totalSteps for the dividend but mathStuff uses stepCount, also try converting to double before the division Double(stepCount) / Level.expRequired() * 100

Comment: @EdwynZN sorry for not clarifying, but the line of code right before mathStuff is just totalSteps = stepCount

I'll update the question and try your suggestion!

Comment: thats ok, either way you should try as mentioned, converting to double before doing the division and not to the division result itself

Comment: @kasprdev, did the answer solve your problem or is there something else that wasn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem probably lies here: 2117 /2500, both `2500` and `2117` are `Int`s.

If they were `Double`, then it would work: `2117.0 /2500.0` ==> produces non-zero division

Try casting those variables to double first, and you don't need to cast the result itself:
`Double(stepCount) /Double(Level.expRequired()))*100`

In fact, I believe only one needs to be cast:
`Double(stepCount)/Level.expRequired())*100`

Comment: @kasprdev did the above solution solve your problem?